# unable to run zmq using task scheduler but it is running normally

Tags: python-3.x, zeromq

unable to run zmq using task scheduler but it is running normally
Dll load failed is the error I am getting but I was able to run it normally from anaconda prompt
[error I'm getting is in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRoT2.png)

Answer (score 0):

adding the following directories to your env path variables will solve the problem: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\usr\bin C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin